# Passing empty arguments to executables using powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line

Powershell seems to drop empty string arguments when passed to a command. I have this code

```
PS D:\> $b.name = "foo bar"
PS D:\> ./echoargs $b.name
Arg 0 is D:\echoargs.exe
Arg 1 is foo bar
PS D:\> $b.name = ""
PS D:\> ./echoargs $b.name
Arg 0 is D:\echoargs.exe
```

You can assume that $b has a 'name' member. How can i pass this as an argument to the exe even when the value is an empty string. I've tried using the call operator with no success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want an empty string to appear try escaped quotes around the argument like so:

```
PS> $b = [psobject]@{name = ''}
PS> echoargs `"$($b.Name)`"
Arg 0 is <>

Command line:
"C:\Users\Keith\Pscx\Trunk\Src\Pscx\bin\Release\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  ""
```

Note that I tested this on V3 so I'm not sure if the behavior will be exactly the same on V2.

Answer (score 12):

Try to pass an empty single quote string enclosed in double quotes, or vice versa.

```
./echoargs $b.name, "''"
```

or

```
./echoargs $b.name, '""'
```

Comment: I tested both methods in PS v5 and the first one didn't work, but the second one did: `./echoargs $b.name, '""'`. The comma between parameters did not appear to be necessary in my case.

Answer (score 3):

This should also work:

```
./echoargs [String]::Empty
```

Comment: Does not seem to work with PowerShell v5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell now works like other shells, and this works as expected out of the box. It does break the workarounds, though. You can support all versions with the workarounds and:

```
if ($PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing) {
    $PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing = 'Legacy'
};
./echoargs $b.name '""'
```

Of course, if you can just use powershell 7.3+, then it's now just

```
./echoargs $b.name ""
```

like all the other shells.