# Why does PowerShell handle empty string differently on the command line?

Tags: powershell, command-line, executable

This question is similar to [Passing empty arguments to executables using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10297002/115690) but I want to expand upon both the question and the answer and understand the "why" better, because it seems like a PowerShell pitfall.

If you load up PSCX and run `echoargs` (an external command, i.e. an exe file) you can see that the empty string argument is skipped:

```
PS> echoargs word "two words" "" 123
Arg 0 is <word>
Arg 1 is <two words>
Arg 2 is <123>
```

But if you use the "CMD escape" (`--%`) you can make it appear "properly":

```
PS> echoargs --% word "two words" "" 123
Arg 0 is <word>
Arg 1 is <two words>
Arg 2 is <>
Arg 3 is <123>
```

Similarly if one writes a PowerShell function the empty string is properly handled:

```
PS> Show-Args word "two words" "" 123
Arg 0 is <word>
Arg 1 is <two words>
Arg 2 is <>
Arg 3 is <123>
```

This difference seems like a big deal to me for the following reason. The examples as shown above use a literal empty string on the command-line so at least you have a hint of the problem. *But the results are exactly the same if one uses a variable containing an empty string.* Which means one has to either:

1. rigorously police all variables being fed to external commands, or
2. use the CMD escape (--%) and forego using any PowerShell constructs on the rest of the line
3. quote every argument to an external command with backquote/double quote like `` `"this`" `` or `` `"$this`" `` or `` `"`" ``

...or bad things will happen!

*(@KeithHill pointed out the third workaround above so I added it there for completeness. It works for literals or variables so, though ugly, is perhaps the best choice of the three workarounds.)*

So PowerShell handles arguments to a function differently than arguments to an external command--dramatically so. Is this an inconsistency in PowerShell's behavior? If not, why not?

---

**Addendum**

For reference, here's the PowerShell function body used above:

```
function Show-Args()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $args.length; $i++)
    {
        Write-Host ("Arg {0} is <{1}>" -f $i, $args[$i])
    }   
}
```

And here is an echoargs-equivalent in C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Arg {0} is <{1}>", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Relevant github issue: [Arguments for external executables aren't correctly escaped #1995](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995).

Answer (score 2):

The behavior might be considered "by design" (it's hard to know for sure based on the implementation and tests), but I don't think the matter was given much thought and you bring up excellent points.

Personally I think you are right and PowerShell is being inconsistent.  It's worth considering a change to be consistent, though that has some risk of breaking existing scripts.

Comment: Yeah, the handling of empty string arguments to applications does seem, um, wrong. ;-)  To be fair, this issue exists at least as far back as V2.